# ListView Delete Button on Checkbox checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I need the following flow to work out:
Once I tap to check any of my listview items checkboxes, a Delete Button should appear. If I uncheck all checkboxes, the Delete Button should disappear.
My problem is that once make a setOnCheckedChangeListener to make Delete visible/gone, on my CheckBox View, it will automatically uncheck itself, after I scroll the listview, and it is not visible any more on my screen (`cause of recycling the views).

Any ideas on how to get a total_number_of_checkboxes_checked variable, that would increase or decrease with 1. (I repeat, counting all checkboxes checked, not only the visible on screen ones).

EDIT: added code

---

### Adapter

---

```
public class AdminNotesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<AdminNoteShortenHolder> mNotesList = new ArrayList<AdminNoteShortenHolder>();

private AdminNoteShortenHolder mNoteHolder = new AdminNoteShortenHolder();
private ViewHolder holder = null;

private Activity activity;

public AdminNotesAdapter(ArrayList<AdminNoteShortenHolder> array,
        Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.mNotesList = array;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNotesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mNoteHolder = mNotesList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.row_adminnotes, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                        mNotesList.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);

                    }
                });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.cb_row_adminnotesCheck,
                holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.img_row_adminnotesNew
            .setVisibility(0 == mNoteHolder.note_read ? View.VISIBLE
                    : View.GONE);

    holder.txt_row_adminnotesNoteSubject.setText(mNoteHolder.note_subject);
    holder.txt_row_adminnotesNoteUser.setText("from "
            + mNoteHolder.note_from_user + " | " + mNoteHolder.note_time);
    holder.txt_row_adminnotesNotePreview.setText(mNoteHolder.note_content);

    holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck.setTag(position);
    holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck.setChecked(mNotesList.get(position)
            .isSelected());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    public ImageView img_row_adminnotesNew;
    public TextView txt_row_adminnotesNoteSubject;
    public TextView txt_row_adminnotesNoteUser;
    public TextView txt_row_adminnotesNotePreview;
    public CheckBox cb_row_adminNotesCheck;

    public ViewHolder(View convertView) {

        img_row_adminnotesNew = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_row_adminnotesNew);

        txt_row_adminnotesNoteSubject = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_row_adminnotesNoteSubject);
        txt_row_adminnotesNoteUser = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_row_adminnotesNoteUser);
        txt_row_adminnotesNotePreview = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_row_adminnotesNotePreview);
        cb_row_adminNotesCheck = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.cb_row_adminnotesCheck);

    }

}
}
```

### AdminNoteShortenHolder (Model class)

```
public class AdminNoteShortenHolder extends BaseHolder {

public int note_id;
public String note_from_user;
public String note_subject;
public String note_content;
public String note_time;
public int note_read;

private boolean selected;

@Override
public void parse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

    note_id = jsonObject.optInt("note_id", -1);
    note_from_user = jsonObject.optString("note_from_user");
    note_subject = jsonObject.optString("note_subject");
    note_content = jsonObject.optString("note_content");
    note_time = jsonObject.optString("note_time");
    note_read = jsonObject.optInt("note_read", -1);
}

public boolean isSelected() {

    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

This is what I've done so far, so I managed to maintain the CheckBoxes status over the scrolling of the ListView with the help of setTag / getTag. Problem is, I have a Delete Button in my Activity that should be visible/gone whenever there is at least one Checkboxes checked or none..
Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: the view is not the place to store data because, as you said, they're being recycled. The checked status of a check box is data for your case. You must store that information in a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html

Comment: Could you please provide me an example on how to use that?

Comment: just make `boolean[] myCheckedStatus = new boolean[numberOfItems]` and on each click you invert the value on that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain/preserve the state of 'checked' checkboxes, to keep it checked on scrolling up and down, because on scrolling list view up/down, every list-item is re-created by the list adapter.

You can use hashMap to hold list-item as s KEY and 'Checked' status as a value. 
When user check mark the box, add key value to map and When user uncheck the box than remove key from map.

Use this map in rendering list view. Code is as below :

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> map =  new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();    

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     Boolean present = map.get(position);
     if(present != null && present.booleanValue()){
       // set checkbox checked
     } else {
       // set checkbox un-cheked
     }

     holder.cb_row_adminNotesCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    mNotesList.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);
                    if(isChecked){
                       map.put(position, true);
                    } else {
                       map.remove(position);
                    }
                    setButtonVisibility();
                }
     });
}

 private void setButtonVisibility()
 {
    if(map.size() > 0){
       // set button visible
    } else {
       // set button invisible
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I find myself in a bit of confusion, maybe I haven't explained myself right. I added some code that I managed to write so far, and some other explanations to my question.

Comment: Your problem is How/when to set delete button visible/gone?

Comment: exactly (when/where/depending on what)

Comment: So where should I make my Delete Button visible/gone .. !?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time spent and answer!